# How can I install neofetch on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install neofetch on CentOS 7, but I can't seem to find the package. Is there any repository I need or do I need to install it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`neofetch` is but a single shell script file. That's the whole idea: you don't need any grand dependencies to install it. You can just download and execute it.

So, a simple

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/7.1.0/neofetch > neofetch
```

downloads it, and `bash neofetch` then executes it. Make it executable (`chmod 755 neofetch`) and put it into a location within your `$PATH` to make it executable as a "freestanding" `neofetch` command.

Of course, following [official installation instructions](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Installation) (as cited by LeoDog896) has many advantages:

1. Being able to uninstall (instead of having to `rm` the file)
2. Getting the `man` page
3. Getting updates

(end of list)

---

Usually, I'd always recommend going through packaging. Even for scripts like that – especially because of the maintainability/update aspects. But! `neofetch` is a tool to gather information on a system, most commonly used to send in information for support. Why would I need to be reminded what operating system I run myself? So, I guess a common use case is "tell the person you're giving support to execute this line of code and copy and paste the result".

"Copy `curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/7.1.0/neofetch | bash` and send me the result" does that one-time job better than "install a third-party package source, update the package lists, then install the neovim package, then run neovim, and send me the result`.

Answer (score 2):

You need the neofetch repository from fedorainfracloud.org. Once you have this, you can install neofetch with `yum`.

```bash
curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/konimex-neofetch-epel-7.repo https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/konimex/neofetch/repo/epel-7/konimex-neofetch-epel-7.repo
yum install neofetch
```